# Xamarin Native PCL in Visual Studio 2015 - New App errors

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

So I am trying to create a new app with Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin, I created a new Cross Platform Native Portable app, I try to install AppCompat Library and immediately throws errors, so far I got these:

- The element 'LinearLayout' has invalid child element 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar'.
- No resource found for ... (multiple of these)

I am trying to create a left drawer but with these errors I cant move forward. So far I have tried to delete all Xamarin Library files from **C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Xamarin** to no avail and searching everywhere on google and here noone has found a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please try to delete your project's `bin/obj` folder and see if that resolves half of the issue. Secondly, can you copy/paste these errors into your question? Please also post the Version of Xamarin and Xamairn.Android in your original post.

Comment: deleting the bin/obj folder seems to have solved the issue, I was wondering why is that doing it fixes the issues, is there any kind of conflict somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete the `bin/obj` folders, it will clear out a previous build cache that might have a potential conflict with the support libs. This is a known issue that I've still been trying to figure out myself. When I run into it again I'll report a bug on it internally.